# Backup Notification Led (Pulse Light) Configuration

Tags: cyanogenmod, settings, backup, notification-led

I recently switched from CyanogenMod to Paranoid Android on my Nexus. I knew I would lose most of my settings, but I felt rather stupid when I realised I had lost all of my carefully defined Pulse Light per-app configurations.

Given that this is quite likely to happen again, **I'd like to know
whether there's a way to back up these settings**.

I'm talking about `Settings > Display > Pulse notification light`,
where you can configure how each specific app should blink and which
colors they should use.

I already use Titanium Backup, but I couldn't find any item in its list
which seemed to regard the pulse light.

Comment: Though I'm using paranoid android at the moment, I'm relatively confident that any method which works with cyanogen will work on it as well (given that this feature seems to have been forked from cyanogen).

Comment: Hmmm, curious, in stock Android (4.2.2) the "Pulse notification light" setting is simply an on/off switch.

Comment: @w3d in cyanogenmod it's goes to a separate customization menu, where you can set the color and pattern off each app.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Light Flow](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rageconsulting.android.lightflowlite&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsImNvbS5yYWdlY29uc3VsdGluZy5hbmRyb2lkLmxpZ2h0Zmxvd2xpdGUiXQ..) app to control my notifications light. It has an option to backup/restore settings that I have used when flashing new ROM or doing a data reset.

Answer (score 0):

On CyanogenMod 11 snapshot M8 I have the notification LED setting in

```
/data/data/com.androdid.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
```

This is the main settings database and contains most (if not all) of them. You probably don't want to transfer the whole bunch, so you have to extract it.

At first, there were 2 files in my backup: `settings.db` (the interesting database) and `settings.db-journal` (its "rollback journal"). The journal contains data that were yet not transferred to the database due to unfinished transactions or maybe for some other reason. Still, before dealing with the database itself, it's better to process the journal. This little (Linux) command did the trick for me:

```
$ sqlite3 settings.db VACUUM
```

After this, the journal should be merged into the database and removed. I've found that the LED settings we are interested in are in the system table. This will get them for you:

```
$ sqlite3 settings.db "SELECT name,value FROM system WHERE name LIKE 'notification_light_pulse%';"
```

I suppose the most interesting ones are:

```
notification_light_pulse_call_color
notification_light_pulse_vmail_color
notification_light_pulse_custom_values
```

I'm afraid I don't know a good way how to transfer those values to your current settings database, though. You should definitely be able to stay with the `sqlite3` tool, maybe use its `.dump` meta-command and then filter it and insert the selected values into your database. This might get messy, though, as the indexes might differ. I'm really no database guy, sorry. Maybe some GUI tool like [SQLite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) might be easier for the job.

Should someone know a good and easy way I'll be glad to update this response.